# ES7 promises and awaiting async function which loops forever in background

Tags: javascript, promise, amazon-sqs, ecmascript-2017

This might be a special case:

I want to read from a queue (AWS SQS), which is done by making a call which waits a few secs for messages, and then resolves - and call again and again in a loop as long as you want to process that queue (it checks a flag every time).

This means that I have a `consume` function which is running as long as the app is active, or the queue is unflagged.

And I also have a `subscribe` function used for subscribing to a queue - which is supposed to resolve as soon as it knows that the consumer is able to connect to the queue. Even though this functions calls the consumer which keeps running and does not return until the queue is unflagged.

It gives me some challenges - do you have any tips on how to solve this with modern JS and async/await promises? I keep in mind this code is running in a React web app, not in node.js.

I basically just want the `await subscribe(QUEUE)` call (which comes from the GUI) to resolve as soon as it's sure that it can read from that queue. But if it cannot, I want it to throw an error which is propagated to the origin of the subscribe call - which means that I have to `await consume(QUEUE)`, right?

Update: 
Some untested draft code has been added (I don't want to spend more time making it work if I'm not doing the right approach) - I thought about sending success and failure callback to the consuming function, so it can report a success as soon as it gets the first valid (but possibly empty) response from the queue, which makes it store the queue url as a subscription - and unsubscribe if as the queue poll fails.

Since I'm setting up several queue consumers they should not be blocking anything but just work in the background

```
let subscribedQueueURLs = []

async function consumeQueue(
  url: QueueURL,
  success: () => mixed,
  failure: (error: Error) => mixed
) {
  const sqs = new AWS.SQS()
  const params = {
    QueueUrl: url,
    WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
  }

  try {
    do {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      const receivedData = await sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise()
      if (!subscribedQueueURLs.includes(url)) {
        success()
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
      for (const message of receivedData.Messages) {
        console.log({ message })
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        eventHandler && (await eventHandler.message(message, url))

        const deleteParams = {
          QueueUrl: url,
          ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle,
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        const deleteResult = await sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams).promise()
        console.log({ deleteResult })
      }
    } while (subscribedQueueURLs.includes(url))
  } catch (error) {
    failure(error)
  }
}

export const subscribe = async (entityType: EntityType, entityId: EntityId) => {
  const url = generateQueueURL(entityType, entityId)
  consumeQueue(
    url,
    () => {
      subscribedQueueURLs.push(url)
      eventHandler && eventHandler.subscribe(url)
    },
    error => {
      console.error(error)
      unsubscribe(entityType, entityId)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: The "modern" way to approach it would be to use an async iterator - `yield` tasks as they come from the queue and consume them with a `for await` expression. That said - they are not the only correct or necessarily best way to do it - there are tradeoffs.

Comment: You probably want an asynchronous design, not a polliong design.  For example, write a `readNextMessage()` asynchronous operation that returns a promise immediately (no need to wait) and then resolves the promise when a message arrives.  After processing that resolved promise, the caller can then just call `readNextMessage()` again.  Or change the whole design to an event-driven design where you just trigger an event (which there can be one or more listeners to) whenever a message arrives.

Comment: @jfr I am already sending the messages to an eventhandler, which decodes them and updates the app state accordingly.

What is the difference between a do - while where I await sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise(), and a where I wrap this in a readNextMessage() ?

Comment: Too abstract for me to comment further without seeing code.  I'd have to see actual code.  You sounded like you had a polling design which is generally not a favored design pattern in node.js.  I was suggesting you stop polling and just use an async notification when a message becomes available - no need to poll.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added some code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this - maybe not the most elegant solution though...

```
let eventHandler: ?EventHandler
let awsOptions: ?AWSOptions
let subscribedQueueUrls = []
let sqs = null
let sns = null


export function setup(handler: EventHandler) {
  eventHandler = handler
}

export async function login(
  { awsKey, awsSecret, awsRegion }: AWSCredentials,
  autoReconnect: boolean
) {
  const credentials = new AWS.Credentials(awsKey, awsSecret)
  AWS.config.update({ region: awsRegion, credentials })
  sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' })
  sns = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31' })
  const sts = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: '2011-06-15' })
  const { Account } = await sts.getCallerIdentity().promise()
  awsOptions = { accountId: Account, region: awsRegion }
  eventHandler && eventHandler.login({ awsRegion, awsKey, awsSecret }, autoReconnect)
}


async function handleQueueMessages(messages, queueUrl) {
  if (!sqs) {
    throw new Error(
      'Attempt to subscribe before SQS client is ready (i.e. authenticated).'
    )
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const message of messages) {
    if (!eventHandler) {
      return
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    await eventHandler.message({
      content: message,
      queueUrl,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    })

    const deleteParams = {
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
      ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle,
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    await sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams).promise()
  }
}


export async function subscribe(queueUrl: QueueUrl) {
  if (!sqs) {
    throw new Error(
      'Attempt to subscribe before SQS client is ready (i.e. authenticated).'
    )
  }

  const initialParams = {
    QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    WaitTimeSeconds: 0,
    MessageAttributeNames: ['All'],
    AttributeNames: ['All'],
  }

  const longPollParams = {
    ...initialParams,
    WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
  }

  // Attempt to consume the queue, and handle any pending messages.
  const firstResponse = await sqs.receiveMessage(initialParams).promise()
  if (!subscribedQueueUrls.includes(queueUrl)) {
    subscribedQueueUrls.push(queueUrl)
    eventHandler && eventHandler.subscribe(queueUrl)
  }
  handleQueueMessages(firstResponse.Messages, queueUrl)

  // Keep on polling the queue afterwards.
  setImmediate(async () => {
    if (!sqs) {
      throw new Error(
        'Attempt to subscribe before SQS client is ready (i.e. authenticated).'
      )
    }
    try {
      do {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        const received = await sqs.receiveMessage(longPollParams).promise()

        handleQueueMessages(received.Messages, queueUrl)
      } while (sqs && subscribedQueueUrls.includes(queueUrl))
    } catch (error) {
      eventHandler && eventHandler.disconnect()
      throw error
    }
  })
}
```